# Inbound Traffic, Spoofed IPv4 + Block real IPv4

Tags: networking, ip, ddos

I have a question about DDoS attacks.
(I do not understand 100% of networks, but I will try to express myself correctly, I apologize for any typos)

Let's say I'm getting real 200Mbps traffic to a specific IP (no spoof), I could stop the attack and I have a link that connects through PPPOE (for example: in BGP case), if I block on main router (where I receive the internet) the IP of the attacker to not receive traffic in any of my devices:
Incoming (Direct on the router)
forward (For the devices that are contained in the router)
Outgoing (Of the equipments that are contained in the reotador for the IP)
Would I continue to get traffic or would I be NullRouted?

If the answer is yes, is it possible to prevent IP spoofs?
Well in the case of spoof I'm getting it like this:

Attack:

```
[Outgoing]
srcip: x.x.x.x [Real]
spoofIP: 8.8.8.8
dstip: 201.80.0.196 [My IP]

[Incoming]
None, because the IP is spoofed
```

My Router:

```
[Incoming]
srcip: 8.8.8.8
dstip: 201.80.0.196

[Outgoing]
srcip: 201.80.0.196
dstip: 8.8.8.8
```

Another problem:
But if I block the incoming traffic and exit from 1 IP Valid this would not be good:

```
iptables ... -A INPUT -s 8.8.8.8 -j DROP
iptables ... -A OUTPUT -d 8.8.8.8 -j DROP
```

Is there a firewall rule to prevent the "INPUT" and "OUTPUT" of spoofed ip? [in case I'm referring to Invalid IP's]

Comment: Not a programming question, hence does not belong on StackOverflow.  General networking questions belong on https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com.  Questions specifically on iptables in Linux belong on https://unix.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: That said, to stop the attack from a specific spoofed source address (8.8.8.8 in your example) you want create a policy-based-routing filter that matches on the source address for incoming traffic and drops it.  In practice, the approach of blocking specific source addresses is of limited use since DDOS attacks are typically originated from a botnet and hence use many different (apparently valid) source addresses.